# GET and POST request in one action. Playframework. Scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming, playframework-2.0

Action create shows form:

```
def create = Action {
    Ok(html.post.create(postForm))
}
```

How can i modify this action so that for GET request it would give out form and for the POST request it would process user input data, as if it were a separate action:

```
def newPost = Action { implicit request =>
   postForm.bindFromRequest.fold(
       errors => BadRequest(views.html.index(Posts.all(), errors)),
       label => {
           Posts.create(label)
           Redirect(routes.Application.posts)
       }
   )
}
```

Wthat i mean is i want to combine this two actions.

UPDATE1: I want a single Action that serves GET and POST requests

Comment: Do you want a single ``Action`` that serves both (GET and POST) requests, or do you want a single route with two distinct actions (as illustrated by @paradigmatic)?

Comment: Yes, i want a single Action that serves GET and POST requests

Comment: I am not familiar with Play, but I see that the ``Request`` class provides a ``method`` method. Assuming that it returns either "POST" or "GET", can't you route both to the same action and then match on ``method``?

Comment: As far as i understand Request class is trait (http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/2.0.2/scala/index.html#play.api.mvc.Request). How can i use `method` method in an action if the Request class is trait?

Comment: You have the ``implicit request`` (of type play.api.mvc.Request) argument to your action, so ``request.method`` should do it. (For the record: I agree with the other commenters in that it is clearer to not merge the two.)

Comment: thanks alot, you've been a great help. I have some difficulties in switching for imperative language to functional language. Could your recommend a good book on functional programming (Scala).

Comment: Pointing out the obvious ... search "scala functional book" on SO and you'll find plenty of references. And never forget to learnyouahaskell.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried once to accomplish similar thing, but I realized that I wasn't using framework like it was meant to be used. Use separate GET and POST methods like @paradigmatic showed and in cases like you specified `"If we take adding comments to another action, we wouldn't be able to get infomation on post and comments in case an error occured (avoding copy-paste code)."` - just render the page at the end of controller method with the view you like? and for errors etc. you can always use flash scope too? `http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.2/ScalaSessionFlash` you could also render this form page with two or more beans and send them to controller side to catch related error messages and data.?

Comment: And in this case, writing couple lines of same code to controller actions is not that big thing since you also get more understandable program structure.

Comment: Thx for sharing your expierence. I try to look differently on this langauge and functional programming in general.

Answer (score 4):

It is recommended not to merge both actions, but modify routes to get the behavior you are expecting. For instance:

```
GET    /create    controllers.Posts.create
POST   /create    controllers.Posts.newPost
```

In case you have several kind of resources (post and comments, for instance), just add
a prefix to the path to disambiguate:

```
GET    /post/create       controllers.Posts.create
POST   /post/create       controllers.Posts.newPost
GET    /comment/create    controllers.Comments.create
POST   /comment/create    controllers.Comments.newComment
```

Comment: Lets look at the example of a page which contains post and comments to the post and the form:
in this action `showpost` we have to get information on post and comments. If we take adding comments to another action, we wouldn't be able to get infomation on post and comments in case an error occured (avoding copy-paste code). That's why i suggested that we unite two actions.

Comment: Here the question is no longer about routing. I'm more interested in the implementation of actions